# Why customize the UITableViewCell click event will automatically respond to

Tags: ios, swift

As the title describes,the cell's click event will auto respondse when tableview is initialized.
I created a xib tableViewCell and swift file, I just do some simple value assignment and layout constraints

```
var model:SFmodel?{
    didSet{
        cardIdLable.text = model!.cardId
        nameLable.text = model!.name
        avtarImg.layer.cornerRadius = avtarImg.size.width / 2
        avtarImg.layer.masksToBounds = true
        avtarImg.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: model!.iconName))
    }  
}
override func awakeFromNib() {

    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    let contentView = self.contentView
    contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    avtarImg.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)
    avtarImg.sd_layout().topSpaceToView(contentView,5).leftSpaceToView(contentView,5).heightIs(40).widthIs(40)       nameLable.sd_layout().topSpaceToView(contentView,5).leftSpaceToView(avtarImg,5).widthIs(100).heightIs(20)     cardIdLable.sd_layout().topSpaceToView(nameLable,2).leftSpaceToView(avtarImg,8).widthIs(100).heightIs(10)
    nameLable.setSingleLineAutoResizeWithMaxWidth(180)
    cardIdLable.setSingleLineAutoResizeWithMaxWidth(180)
}
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    print("has response")
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide more context to your question.

Comment: And please post code, not screenshots

Comment: You edited the question but it is still unclear.

Comment: @Coder1000  I have been updated.please check it

Comment: @AndyIbanez I created a viewcontroller inherited from the TableViewcontroller, in the viewcontroller I use custom tableViewCell, the problem is: every time when I initialize the view controller, the tableViewCell setSelected will automatically execute. and don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setSelected also gets called when a cell is not selected. If you want it only to get called when the cell is ACTUALLY selected you need to check the selected bool like:

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    if selected {
        print("has response")
    }
}
```

Comment: that's it,think you.